# SqlAlechemy subqueryload_all with filter

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Hi there I would like to do something like this

```
tasks = session.query(User).filter(User.id == user_id).options(subqueryload_all(User.tasks)).filter(Task.title.like("%"+substring+"%")).one().tasks
```

so basically select all user tasks which title contains substring

Any ideas why my code is not working?
:) thanks

**EDIT:**
by not working I mean that it give a wrong result... it returns all User.tasks without applied filter

Comment: Please explain "not working": error, exception, wrong result?

Comment: @van see Edit in question, thanks

Comment: Coudl you please specify what would you like to achive? "For given user get all tasks which match the filter"? or "For all users get all tasks which match the filter"? It is really not clear from your query what are you looking to get as a result. What your query does right now is the following: "Get *all* tasks for the first (not sure about sorting here) user in the database which has at least one task matching the criteria". This is why you get *all* the tasks.

Comment: @van I want to get user's tasks which title contains some substring.... for example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like you're expecting the collection loaded by the subqueryload to be affected by the filter on Task.   The eager loading options don't work this way; they are never impacted by the rest of the query.  Read [The Zen of Eager Loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/loading.html#the-zen-of-eager-loading) for background.

in this case, you can either use a join with [contains_eager](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/loading.html#contains-eager) or you can roll your own subqueryload using the [disjoint eager loading](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/DisjointEagerLoading) recipe, which is the precursor to the subquery eager loading feature.